# Picasso doesn't load some images

Tags: android, retrofit2, picasso

I want to load some images from server to imageView using Picasso but the Picasso loads some of them and others aren't loaded.
Does anyone know of a solution for this kind of a situation?

```
Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true);
         Picasso
         .with(context)
         .load("http://192.168.1.6:8080/images/" + retroRepo.getImages_hashes().trim())
         .resize(200, 200)
         .into(holder.imageView);
```

when I search http://192.168.1.6:8080/images/myImage.jpg it shows the image.

Comment: http://192.168.1.6:8080/images/myImage.jpg image is not loading in browser also please check link.

Comment: I don't see a image on your URL.

Comment: is the device connected to your home wifi?

Comment: it's local link, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: I am using a localhost.my device is connected to home wifi.

Comment: try to add .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) too and  add  error image,so that you can check where it is error or not

Answer (score 1):

Make sure images are available, if yes then please check with the size, extension of that images. Sometimes sizes and extensions make hurdles in loading.
Please verify response with this callback.

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //do smth when picture is loaded successfully

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            //do smth when there is picture loading error
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I have two jpg images. One load and other one doesn't load.

Comment: Please check with your adapter code. Maybe you are not referencing the right imageview for loading.

Comment: in loaded images, it is successful and in not loaded images error occurs.

Comment: Then for sure this is not android side issue. There is some issue related to your server side.

Comment: I get some images successfully but in some others, I don't get them

Answer (score 0):

You have the posted ip address of your localhost, image is not available on server so others can access this.

Please add Log.d("image: ", ""+retroRepo.getImages_hashes().trim());

and make sure it is not null or empty. Post this log value here.

Comment: Log.d("image: ", ""+"http://192.168.1.6:8080/images/" + retroRepo.getImages_hashes().trim());

Comment: D/image:: http://192.168.1.6:8080/images/5FJCPB80CVWYA4LJBD2491PONPN8VLKCCLV3EQI8MTR1MNW304S9CC5QKWPHK1OO.jpg
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R1]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R1]+9ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R1]+91ms for error
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R1]+332ms 
D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1]+342ms

Comment: I'm sure it's not null or empty

Comment: The log statement you provided does not shows image name. it should be like  192.168.1.6:8080/images/xyz.jpg (*.jpg is extention of the image you have).

Comment: Also make sure  retroRepo.getImages_hashes() is not returning list of images

Comment: retroRepo.getImages_hashes() should be a single image with extention. In case it returning list then you should add this in for loop. passing single object to the URL. e.g.   if(retroRepo.getImages_hashes() != null ){
for(i = 0; i<= retroRepo.getImages_hashes().size(); i++){
Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true);
         Picasso
         .with(context)
         .load("http://192.168.1.6:8080/images/" + retroRepo.getImages_hashes().get(i))
         .resize(200, 200)
         .into(holder.imageView);
  
  }
  }